# Struts2 if tag not working

Tags: java, struts2

I am writing a login page that when a invalid user tries to login I redirect to the login action with a error parameter equal to 1.

```
private String username;
private String password;
private int error;
@Override
public String execute()
{
    //validate user input
    if (username == null || password == null || username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty())
    {
        error = 2;
        return LOGIN;   
    }

    LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel(username, password);

    HttpBuilder<LoginModel, User> builder = new HttpBuilder<LoginModel, User>(User.class);
    builder.setPath("service/user/authenticate");
    builder.setModel(loginModel);

    IHttpRequest<LoginModel, User> request = builder.buildHttpPost();
    User user = request.execute(URL.BASE_LOCAL);

    //redirects to login page
    if (user == null)
    {
        error = 1;
        return LOGIN;
    }
    else
    {   
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}

   //Getters/Setters
```

If a invalid user trys to login it redirects to localhost:8080/app/login.action?error=1. I am trying to display a error message to user by access the error parameter by using the if tag but its not working the message is not displaying.

```
<s:if test="error == 1">
<center>
    <h4 style="color:red">Username or Password is invalid!!</h4>
</center>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show your `struts.xml` file.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm concerned what you're doing wrong is completely ignoring the framework.

Roughly, IMO this should look more like this:

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Override
    public String validate() {
        if (isBlank(username) || isBlank(password)) {
            addActionError("Username or Password is invalid");
        }

        User user = loginUser(username, password);
        if (user == null) {
            addActionError("Invalid login");
        }
    }

    public User loginUser(String username, String password) {
        LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel(username, password);

        HttpBuilder<LoginModel, User> builder = new HttpBuilder<LoginModel, User>(User.class);
        builder.setPath("service/user/authenticate");
        builder.setModel(loginModel);

        IHttpRequest<LoginModel, User> request = builder.buildHttpPost();
        return request.execute(URL.BASE_LOCAL);
    }

}
```

You would have an `"input"` result containing the form, and display any action errors present using whatever style you wanted. If it's *critical* to change the styling based on which type of login error it is you'd have to play a few more games, but that seems excessive.

Unrelated, but I'd move that `loginUser` code *completely* out of the action and into a utility/service class, but at least with it wrapped up in a separate method you can mock it more easily. It certainly does *not* belong in the `execute` method.

Comment: Can I get the error message to be displayed when using redirectAction result type to the jsp page of that action?

Comment: Why are you redirecting to show the login page again? Aren't you already on the login page?

Comment: @MarioDennis I'm also not sure why you'd need to redirect, but you could use the message store interceptor.

Comment: The reason I redirect to an Action is because there is default action to display the login page and a action to process the user login (authenicate the user). If the user login action succeeds then it redirects to a action that display users personal page if it fails it redirects to login action that displays the login page. What I want to do now is display the error on that page can this be done a  better way and how can I get the error to display using this approach if possible.

Comment: @MarioDennis Use the message store interceptor? But it still makes no sense; forward to the login page.

Comment: what should I do then if not redirect to the login page?

Comment: Forward? What's the point of a redirect? All you need to do is display the form again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the **getter** and **setter** of field 'error' to access it from  value stack.

```
public int getError() 
{
   return error;
}

public void setError(int error) 
{
   this.error = error;
}
```

And try to access it in OGNL:

```
<s:if test="%{#error==1}"></s:if>
```

Or using JSTL:

```
<c:if test="${error==1}"></c:if>
```

Comment: I have these methods in the action.